# How do I use the indices of nested for-loops to generate a consecutive list of numbers?

Tags: for-loop

E.g.:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

That's 3 * 4 * 5 = 60 times executing the innerst code. Now I want to use the values of the indices i, j, and k to generate all numbers from 0 to 59 (not necessarily sorted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Make k count 1, j count k's limit, i count j's limit times k's limit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
      int c = k * 1 + j * (5) + i * (5 * 4);
      System.out.println(c);
    }
  }
}
```

Output: 0..59.