# Matlab: How do I use two nested for-loops to generate a consecutive list of numbers in ascending order?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I would like to obtain an array of consecutive numbers from 1 to the product of the limits of two nested loops. I hope the example below will clarify the question. If I have the nested loop:

```
for i = 1:limit_loop_1
    for j = 1:limit_loop_2
        a = ???;
       disp(a)
    end
end
```

I would like to obtain `a = (1:(limit_loop_1*limit_loop_2))'`

For example, having:

```
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:5
       a = ????;
       disp(a)
    end
end
```

I would like to get:

```
a=
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

I found similar questions for Java (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6604502/how-do-i-use-the-indices-of-nested-for-loops-to-generate-a-consecutive-list-of-n)), but nothing for Matlab. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I need this particular procedure because I will use the index to refer to another array. So, if I have for example a 3D array A of size (100,1,15) within the nested loops, I want to consider each one of the 15 elements of the array at each iteration. In code this would be:

```
for k = 1:100
    for i = 1:3
        for j = 1:5
            something = A (k,1,????)
        end
    end
end
```

That is why ????? should go from 1 to 15. Hope this clarify my issue.

Comment: And why not simply use the vector `(1:a*b)`?

Comment: The answer is obviously `a = (1:(limit_loop_1*limit_loop_2))'`. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: I do not understand the downrating. If I say that I need this particular solution it is quite obvious that I cannot use other methods, even if these are easier/more obvious.

Comment: You've already given the fastest and best method to get the number of iterations, which is the vectorised approach. Without knowing *why*  you want to use nested loops, it's kind of silly to do this in a nested-loop way. It's like owning a race car and wanting to exchange it for a bicycle without telling us why you want that. Everyone will tell you it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Giovanni.R88, don't get upset. Please. Most of the users in SO, unfortunately, aim at the best solution not taking into account what the OP wants. Same happened to me in a Python question in which the OP wanted to split a string in several strings and concatenate them in a list. A user proposed a solution but he used a tuple instead of a list. I pointed it out...and I got a downvote. Butthurts.

Comment: @Alessiox: I downvoted the question because it is absolutely trivial to translate the solution the OP already found from Java to MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the solution you already provided (`a = (1:(limit_loop_1*limit_loop_2))'`) is correct and absolutely nice. However if you must use a nested loop, just treat `a` as an external counter

```
a=0;
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:5
       a = a+1;
       disp(a)
    end
end
```

This basically counts how many iteration are made by using the nested loop (3*5 in this case).

Or if you want to exploit the indices `i` and `j` you can re-adapt the Java example in Matlab by taking into account that in Matlab the indices start at 1 whereas in Java they start at 0:

```
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:5
        c =1+(j-1)*1+(i-1)*(5);
        disp(c)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Alessiox, the second part is exactly what I was looking for! Unfortunately I was not able to come up with the right combination of coefficients needed to obtain the result. Thanks also for your comprehension and for sharing with me your experience. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why you'd want to do it this way, but I'll take you at your word. This will give you the results you require:

```
for ii = 1:3
    for jj = 1:5
       a = 5*(ii-1)+jj;
       disp(a)
    end
end
```

(I changed your loop variables from `i` and `j` because they're the imaginary unit variables by default, and some folks get upset if you overwrite them.)

Results:

```
>> loop15
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 11
 12
 13
 14
 15
```